# Prove the following equality: $ \sum_{i=0} ^n j {n \choose j} = n 2^{n-1} $

Tags: induction, binomial-coefficients

I'd like some help. My first idea was to use induction, but then I get stuck. The base case works just fine, as you'd imagine, and then...

- If  $ \sum_{i=0} ^n j {n \choose j} = n 2^{n-1} \rightarrow  \sum_{i=0} ^{n+1} j {n+1 \choose j} = (n+1) 2^{n}  $
  $$ \sum_{i=0} ^{n+1} j {n+1 \choose j} =  \sum_{i=0} ^{n} j {n+1 \choose j}  + n+1 = \sum_{i=0} ^{n} j (n! / ((n-j)!j!))*(n+1)/(n+1-j)  + n+1$$
- And well I can't seem to do anything else.

Another way, also using induction.

$$ \sum_{i=0} ^{n+1} j {n+1 \choose j} = \sum_{i=0} ^{n} j ({n \choose j} - {m \choose j-1}) + m + 1$$

And then I also get stuck.

I know there's another way of proving this without using induction and only with some properties and a couple of tricks I do not see to see.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Hint : $\binom{n}{j} = \binom{n}{n-j}$.

Comment: Another relevant link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351289/simplify-sum-i-0n-i1-binom-ni

Comment: Questions such as this one find usually a quick answer on the internet with evident keywords like "combinatorial identity". One reference that I have found in a couple of minutes is this one (page 3) http://math.ucsd.edu/~jverstra/bijections.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Since you wanted a "trick", consider,
$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}x^i$$
Differentiating with respect to $x$,
$$n(1+x)^{n-1}=\sum_{i=0}^ni\binom{n}{i}x^{i-1}$$
Now substitute $x=1$.