# Compute ${n \choose 0}+2{n \choose 1}+3{n \choose 2} + \cdots + (n+1){n \choose n}$

Tags: combinatorics

I am having trouble doing this question and I do not know where to start. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: And [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplify $\sum_{i=0}^n (i+1)\binom ni$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351289/simplify-sum-i-0n-i1-binom-ni) – found instantly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%7Bn%20%5Cchoose%200%7D%2B2%7Bn%20%5Cchoose%201%7D%2B3%7Bn%20%5Cchoose%202%7D%20%2B%20%5Ccdots%20%2B%20(n%2B1)%7Bn%20%5Cchoose%20n%7D%24&p=1)

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Consider $f(x)={n \choose 0}x+{n \choose 1}x^2+{n \choose 2}x^3 + \cdots + {n \choose n}x^{n+1}$. Write $f(x)=xg(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

For $r\ge1,$

$$(r+1)\binom nr=r\binom nr+\binom nr=n\binom{n-1}{r-1}+\binom nr$$
Now use
$$(1+1)^m=\sum_{r=0}^m\binom mr$$